# how to access files in xamarin.android. And also in Visual Studio Solution explorer where should i place the file in order to locate it in my code

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android

The code below tries to access file named zimbabwe in Asset folder

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText("Asset/zimbabwe.shp")
```

[image: The image below is showing the code ive used to try and access file and the folder where the file is placed]

How should I access files in xamarin.android? And also in Visual Studio Solution explorer where should I place the file in order to locate it in my code?

Answer (score 3):

In Xamarin.Android project, `Assets` are read using an `AssetManager`. An instance of the `AssetManager` is available by accessing the Assets property on an `Android.Content.Context`, such as an Activity.

For example:

```
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("zimbabwe.shp")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

And in Xamarin.Forms project,you could also add any file into the `Assets` folder in the Android project and mark the `Build Action` as `AndroidAsset` to use it with `OpenAppPackageFileAsync`.

```
using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(templateFileName))
{
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    var fileContents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: @LloydNyahwai If it's helpful for you,could you mark it as an accept answer,then it could help others.